# Is the pure existance of a `&[u32]` and `&mut [u32]` to the same data already considered undefined behaviour?

Tags: rust

I am in the process of implementing an SPI driver.

Now I have the following driver code (MRE-ified):

```rust
use tokio::{join, sync::mpsc};

async fn spi_transmit(write_buf: &[u32], read_buf: &mut [u32]) {
    assert_eq!(read_buf.len(), write_buf.len());
    let (write_fifo, mut read_fifo) = mpsc::channel(2);

    let write_task = async {
        // Simulate an SPI bus that respondes with the sent data + 20,
        // just for demo purposes
        for val in write_buf {
            write_fifo.send(*val + 20).await.unwrap();
        }
    };

    let read_task = async {
        for val in read_buf {
            *val = read_fifo.recv().await.unwrap();
        }
    };

    join!(write_task, read_task);
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let buf_out = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    let mut buf_in = [0, 0, 0, 0];

    spi_transmit(&buf_out, &mut buf_in).await;

    println!("{:?}", buf_in);
}
```

```
[21, 22, 23, 24]
```

The central API is `async fn spi_transmit(write_buf: &[u32], read_buf: &mut [u32])`.

Now I need to implement an `async fn spi_transmit_in_place(read_write_buf: &mut [u32])` that transmits and receives from the same buffer, which in the end contains the read data.

I know for a fact that read and write access to the buffer will never overlap, a byte will always be read first and then at a later, non-overlapping time it will be written.

With that knowledge, is it considered sound if I implement it like this, or is this considered undefined behaviour?

```rust
async fn spi_transmit_in_place(read_write_buf: &mut [u32]) {
    let write_buf = unsafe {
        let data = read_write_buf.as_ptr();
        let len = read_write_buf.len();
        std::slice::from_raw_parts(data, len)
    };

    spi_transmit(write_buf, read_write_buf).await
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut buf = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    spi_transmit_in_place(&mut buf).await;
    println!("{:?}", buf);
}
```

```
[21, 22, 23, 24]
```

It works, but [miri is not happy](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7b3d9446b9da53888c644cb1c5acad87).

If this is undefined behavior, does this mean I'm forced to re-implement `spi_transmit` using raw pointers? Or how else could I solve this problem?

Comment: Miri does not have false positives. So if it warns there is UB. The only question is whether it is only UB according to Stacked Borrows or Tree Borrows, or even with what is specified to certainly be UB. In this case, it is certainly UB.

Comment: Can you change `spi_transmit()`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yes, I can. But I feel like if I change it to an unsafe raw pointer based algorithm, I loose some confidence in the correctness of my code.

Comment: *Iff* creating `&UnsafeCell<T>` from `&T` (but never writing into it) is fine (which it is according to Tree Borrows but is UB according to Stacked Borrows), this problem has a very nice solution that does not require `unsafe` inside the function or its callers at all (as opposed to the raw pointer way). But I do not want to post an answer that is UB per SB while the aliasing model is not decided yet...

Comment: Unless... Are you fine with requiring the read buffer to be mutable, even when we're not writing into it?

Comment: Post it as a playground link as a comment here :)
*"Are you fine with requiring the read buffer to be mutable"* - That I sadly can't do because the interface is dictated by https://docs.rs/embedded-hal-async/1.0.0-rc.2/embedded_hal_async/spi/trait.SpiBus.html

Comment: Does this mean your `spi_transmit()` is the trait's method, and needs to have exactly the same API? (Because of yes, you can't change it).

Comment: Yes. I can of course create an internal implementation function that both `transfer` and `transfer_in_place` call, but I can't make the write slice mutable, because that wouldn't be compatible with that API any more.

Comment: *"Can you change `spi_transmit()`?"* Ah I thought you meant the implementation. No, the API can't change. I could of course write a raw pointer based implementation and call it from `spi_transmit` and `spi_transmit_in_place`. What I want to avoid is that I need to implement those two functions separately.

Comment: Yeah, if you can create a function and call it from the trait (and directly in the case of the buffer) this is fine.

Comment: [Here's the demonstration](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7df83cd910978e975c46f22ee2c1c992).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256160/discussion-between-finomnis-and-chayim-friedman).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, about having both a reference and an exclusive reference [Behavior considered undefined](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html) tells us:

> breaking the [pointer aliasing rules](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#pointer-aliasing-rules)

is UB if both references are live, specifically

> Such ranges shall not overlap with any ranges of addresses allocated by mechanisms provided by LLVM

and

> Each time a reference or box is passed to or returned from a function, it is considered live.

creating them and then sequentially accessing them one after the other also makes them live from creation to access and thus you don't even need to call a function to make it UB.

Comment: So is this no longer considered undefined behavior if I code my own slice representation using a pointer and a length?

Comment: Not intrinsically, in part because unlike mutable references raw pointers are not flagged as `noalias`. However you have to be very careful to never concurrently manifest mutable references from such aliasing mutable pointers. The easiest way to do this is probably to use `std::ptr` to interact with raw pointers.