# what is the best "Rust" way to keep read-write control on the object that is already mutably-referenced?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

say I want to test the behavior of a struct (`Consumer`) that takes mutable reference to another struct (`Target`). And the only way to test its correctness is to get direct read-write access to the `Target`. And we guarantee no multi-threading here.

Something like below comes to my mind, though it does not compile due to obvious violation of borrow rules: `t` remains borrowed mutably while we want to borrow it later again.

```
use std::io::Write;

struct Consumer<'a, W: Write> {
    out: &'a mut W
}

impl<'a, W: Write> Consumer<'a, W> {
    pub fn consume(&mut self, data: &[u8]) {
        // do something else
        self.out.write(data).unwrap();
    }
}

struct Target {
    buf: Vec<u8>
}

impl Target {
    pub fn drain(&mut self) {
        self.buf.clear();
    }
}

impl Write for Target {
    fn write(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> std::io::Result<usize> {
        self.buf.extend_from_slice(buf);
        Ok(buf.len())
    }

    fn flush(&mut self) -> std::io::Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }
}

mod tests {
    use crate::{Target, Consumer};

    #[test]
    fn test_that_consumes_ok() {
        let mut t = Target{ buf: Vec::new() };
        let mut c = Consumer{ out: &mut t };
        c.consume(b"hello");
        c.consume(b"world");

        // error in this line:
        assert_eq!(t.buf.as_slice(), b"helloworld");

        // also error:
        t.drain();

        c.consume(b"new");
        assert_eq!(t.buf.as_slice(), b"new");
    }
}


fn main() {}
```

So the question is not about this testing approach itself (which is questionable), rather about how to supply a mutable reference to multiple places without bullet-proof `Arc<Mutex>` way. Intuitively I understand that something like `Rc<RefCell>` would help, but cannot construct it. Please help.

Comment: You can't, any other reference in addition to a mutable reference to the same memory region is immediate UB. See [Is the pure existance of a `&[u32]` and `&mut [u32]` to the same data already considered undefined behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77606083/is-the-pure-existance-of-a-u32-and-mut-u32-to-the-same-data-already-co/77606123#77606123)

Comment: Why can't you use `RefCell`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman would appreciate if someone points me out to how to use RefCell in this case.

Comment: Like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6bbdf2f1fb4350aa6a7c376d0c752ec6. You mentioned this option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To complement's cafce25's comment, and to be clear, just because there's no multithreading doesn't mean there is no unsafety to R|W: for all the compiler knows from the outside `Consumer` keeps references around to `out`'s contents, which a write might invalidate. A classic example is something like

```
fn foo(v: &mut Vec<u8>) {
    let e = &v[0];
    v.push(5);
}
```

In C++ this can lead to an UB, because the `push` can need to resize the vector, which frees the old buffer, which invalidates the `e` reference (it's even more obvious if you clear the vector but that's less likely to pass as innocuous). An other classic one is "iterator invalidation" where you update the contents of a collection while iterating on it, which commonly has the same issue (as the name indicate, the iterator itself can become invalid), and hits even memory-safe languages: some of them start to return nonsense, others will guard against it and trigger a runtime error e.g. the dreaded [`ConcurrentModificationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) in java does not require any threading:

> If a single thread issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of an object, the object may throw this exception. For example, if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this exception.

Here you have multiple ways to handle the issue though:

- The "public" way to do this is to make `Consumer` yield a sub-reference to the `target` it contains. It's a common enough pattern, you can see it with [`BufWriter::get_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufWriter.html#method.get_mut) which allows getting a handle on the underlying writer.
- But because `Consumer` is entirely open (as you can construct it using a struct literal) you can literally just reach into it here:

  ```
  let t = &mut *c.out;
  ```

  will work fine. However that sub-borrow has to be released before you can call `Consumer::consume` again, so you also need to add a copy of that at the bottom, between `c.consume(b"new");` and its assertion.

  Alternatively, you can just replace every `t` by `c.out`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to solve this problem with `RefCell` and `Rc`, by providing an interior-mutable `Write` to the `Consumer`.

```rust
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use std::cell::RefCell;
    use std::rc::Rc;

    #[derive(Clone)]
    struct SharedWrite {
        // this could be generic instead of hardcoding `Target`, if that suits your needs better
        inner: Rc<RefCell<Target>>,
    }

    impl Write for SharedWrite {
        fn write(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> std::io::Result<usize> {
            self.inner.borrow_mut().write(buf)
        }

        fn flush(&mut self) -> std::io::Result<()> {
            self.inner.borrow_mut().flush()
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_that_consumes_ok() {
        let mut t = SharedWrite {
            inner: Rc::new(RefCell::new(Target { buf: Vec::new() })),
        };
        let mut c = Consumer {
            out: &mut t.clone(),
        };
        c.consume(b"hello");
        c.consume(b"world");

        assert_eq!(t.inner.borrow().buf.as_slice(), b"helloworld");

        t.inner.borrow_mut().drain();

        c.consume(b"new");
        assert_eq!(t.inner.borrow().buf.as_slice(), b"new");
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ebc78b0a52d3b451ba3d8c1432f471e0)

Notes:

- I have modified *only* the `tests` module, to show how this can be strictly added in test code. You might choose instead to build the same functionality into `Target` itself, if you wanted.
- `Rc` is not strictly necessary; you could use a `&RefCell<Target>` instead, and that'd be a smidge faster. But `Rc` is frequently useful in this class of situation, so it's worth keeping both options in mind. In particular, `Rc` works even if you need to satisfy `W: 'static`.
- Another option would be to have the `Write` implementation given to the `Consumer` be one which writes to a *channel*, where the test retains the reading/receiving end of the channel.